# Ошибка при отправке формы на сервер: The value '' is invalid

Tags: c#, html

Отправляю на сервер данные из формы, в таблице стоит автоинкремент, но Id все равно приходит пустой. Что можно исправить чтобы Id автоматически присваивался.
Форму отправляю на свой IIS-сервер. Если из формы убрать  выдает ошибку.

```
<form acton="/Home/Index">
<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="FirstName">Фамилия</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="Введите фамилию" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="LastName">Имя</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="small mb-1" for="Email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control py-4" id="Email" name="Email" type="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Введите email адрес" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="Password">Пароль</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="Password" name="Password" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1">Повторите пароль</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" type="password" placeholder="Повторите пароль" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Создать аккаунт</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях, ее потом там трудно будет отыскать, пишите ее сразу в вопрос, вопрос можно редактировать - кнопка Править. А комментарий можно удалить.

Comment: Что за сервер? Ваш или чей-то? Зачем вам вообще постить Id? Уберите его из формы.